# Json parse errors with DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I'm building a table to display order information and I'm having trouble with understanding why the JSON data returns blank when sorting in descending or changing to the second to last page in the table.

The parsing error happens when I sort certain columns from descending to ascending and when I try to go to the second to last page of the table. However when I search something all of the functions come back and work perfectly fine. I tried looking up solutions and found a few articles however none were having the exact same issue as mine or even close to it and the closest one has been closed (https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9220/ajax-sort-descending-on-load). What am I doing wrong?

You can see this happen at: http://aframewerx.com

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dataTable = $('#orderTable').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "responsive": {
      "details": {
        renderer: function ( api, rowIdx ){
          var data = api.cells( rowIdx, ':hidden' ).eq(0).map( function ( cell ) {
            var header = $( api.column( cell.column ).header() );
            return  '<p style="color:#00A">'+header.text()+' : '+api.cell( cell ).data()+'</p>';
          }).toArray().join('');

          return data ?    $('<table/>').append( data ) :    false;
        }
      }
    },
    "ajax":{
      url :"fetch_data.php", // json datasource
      type: "post",  // method  , by default get
      error: function (request, error) {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert("Error: " + error);
        $(".orderTable-error").html("");
        $("#orderTable").append('<tbody class="orderTable-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
        $("#orderTable_processing").css("display","none");
      }
    }

  });

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$requestData= $_REQUEST;
$columns = array( 
    0 => 'order_date', 
    1 => 'due_ship_date',
    2 => 'ordered_by',
    3 => 'pick_status',
    4 => 'order_number',
    5 => 'sku',
    6 => 'qty',
    7 => 'product_title',
    8 => 'variant_title',
    9 => 'product_type',
   10 => 'id'
);

$sql = "SELECT id";
$sql.=" FROM kess_orders";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Failed to connect");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData; 

$sql = "SELECT order_date,due_ship_date,ordered_by,pick_status,order_number,sku,qty,product_title,variant_title,product_type,id ";
$sql.=" FROM kess_orders WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) { 
  $sql.=" AND ( order_date LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
  $sql.=" OR due_ship_date LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR ordered_by LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR pick_status LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR order_number LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR sku LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR product_title LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";

  $sql.=" OR product_type LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Failed to connect");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("fetch_orders.php: get order_number");


$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
  $nestedData=array(); 

  $nestedData[] = '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row["id"].'" name="id">'.$row["order_date"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["due_ship_date"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["ordered_by"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["pick_status"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["order_number"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["sku"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["qty"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["product_title"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["variant_title"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["product_type"];
  $nestedData[] = '<div id=' . $row["id"] . '"><div class="btn-group" id="'.$row["id"].'"><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#'.$row["id"].'" style="padding:0px !important;"><div class="wrapper"><div id="'.$row["id"].'" class="top bar"></div><div id="'.$row["id"].'" class="middle bar"></div><div id="'.$row["id"].'" class="bottom bar"></div></div></a> <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right arrow_box" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style=" margin-right: 35px; top: -6px; min-width:105px;"><li><input type="hidden" value="'.$row["id"].'" name="id"><button class="pull-left  btn btn-danger remove-item button-hover" style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; height: 31px;border-radius: 3px;font-size: 12px;background-color: #2E112D;color:#fff;border:1px solid #2E112D;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li><li><input type="hidden" value="'.$row["id"].'" name="id"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="pull-left button-hover btn btn-primary edit-item" style="margin-right:10px; height: 31px;border-radius: 3px;font-size: 12px;background-color: #2E112D;color:#fff;border:1px solid #2E112D;"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li></ul></div></div>';

  $data[] = $nestedData;
}

$json_data = array(
      "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),
      "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),
      "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
      "data"            => $data
      );

echo json_encode($json_data); 
?>
```

Error:

```
"parsererror", SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at parse
```

Comment: Is this correct in your code: `$requestData= $_REQUEST;`. I don't know how you get `$requestData['search']['value']` and `$requestData['order'][0]['column']` from the `$_REQUEST` superglobal... did you do a json_decode somewhere I'm not seeing?

Comment: Could you also please check your developer tools in your browser, on what is actually returning during the ajax calls. You would find this in the network tab, and look at the 'return' body. It may be spitting php notices, or other weird errors that is fouling up the js json parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @IncredibleHat unfortunately the response in the network tab is blank when sorting to descending however when sorting ascending the response shows the JSON as below: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0214/5074/files/Screen_Shot_2018-02-07_at_12.56.14_PM.png?13347519210839548760

Comment: Blank suggests to me a fatal 500 error with php. Maybe dig into your php error logs? Also turning on some warnings might catch a few too: `ini_set('display_errors', true);  error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking however I'm unsure what would be causing it and why it would become fixed as soon as something is being searched for in the search input (say I search for 2017 in the input field, all of a sudden the sorting and pagination works perfectly). The error log for PHP doesn't show any errors either. I appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Well you have a lot of conditions for the SQL build, so any one of those could cause it to work one way, but not another. I'd start debugging by spitting out the raw SQL command that is fully built, and see if there are any obvious goofs. And possibly adding more mysqli error reporting too on each step. But if you are getting completely 'blank' on the php return, then something is definitely stopping PHP cold (because at the very least, you should have "draw" "recordsTotal" etc in a basic json array.

Comment: After going through every scenario I could think of I realized the data that was being returned was indeed the problem. My JSON data contained an ASCII character which caused the parse error, once the character was taken out everything started working correctly. Can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much for your help @IncredibleHat !